# Get all columns from a table dynamically within a view

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, after I save the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

If I edit **MyView**, the asterix disappears and the SQL contains all the field names.  For example:

```
ALTER VIEW MyView AS SELECT field1, field2 FROM MyTable;
```

When **MyTable** has new fields added to it, I wish for the view output to also display those new fields.  How can I prevent the asterix from being substituted with literal column names?

Answer (score 0):

This is an antipattern. Don't write views with select * - it will come back to bite you.

You can write an autogenerated SQL statement to generate the view code to save you some time if you want by referring to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Comment: I am aware that it is generally bad practice to use asterix, however this is for a generic tool (where the table is expected to change regularly), so it is a special case.  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS sounds like a possible solution though - I'll try that.

Comment: Ah - unfortunately INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS would not work in this case because of locked down permission's.  Do you know of any other potential SQL only solution?